# inline-block div not applying padding correctly

Tags: css, html, css-float

You can see an example here:

http://users.telenet.be/prullen/portfolio_test.html

I have set a padding of 100px (all directions) to the portfolio_item class (3 items on that page). The top, bottom, and left paddings are applied. But the right padding doesn't seem to work; the text extends beyond the boundary of the div.

```
.portfolio_item {
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 100px;
}
```

I have tried changing the div to a float:left instead of display:inline-block but that didn't help.

Ideas are appreciated.

Thank you,
Wesley

Comment: somewhere you must have the width of those <p> elements hardcoded at 500?

Comment: @Forty-Two There is no css declaration for paragraphs on the page.

Comment: just eliminate `.portfolio_item { width: 100%;` and everything is fine.

Comment: @Christoph Actually, no, if there isn't much text then the background doesn't stretch to fill the entire width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying `box-sizing: border-box;` on your `.portfolio_item` should fix the issue. You'll have to include some specific vendor prefixes for this to work on all modern browsers:

```
.portfolio_item {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/8K2sb/).

Comment: yes it did, but I had to wait a couple of more minutes before I could accept an answer. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

More than one parent element (`.out` anb `.in`) has `overflow: hidden;` applied. The overall container is set to a width of 800 pixel and thus the right side of the content is hidden. The padding itself works – you just don't see it in your current setup.

```
<div style="width:800px; border:2px dashed red;">
    <div class="out">
        <div class="in">

<!-- … -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the width of the inside to 100%, but with the padding the width is actually 100% + 200px. I would recommend changing

```
width: 100%;
```

To

```
width: 600px;
```

Or changing the padding to a percent like:

```
width: 80%;
padding: 10%;
```

Comment: So what is the solution? The width needs to be 100%

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the padding needs to be a px value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying the padding to the div, target the text specifically. Place the text in a 'p' tag and call it in the CSS.

```
.portfolio_item p{
     padding: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Actually I do need it around the item, there is no guarantee that only paragraphs are going to be inside there.

Answer (score 0):

you can give like this,

```
 .portfolio_item {
        clear: both;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 100px;
        width: 87%;
    }
```