# input width, padding missmatch

Tags: html, css

I am having a quick and interesting problem.
The padding applied to the input tag, is not being added the width of the input, but rather subtracted.

In the print-screen, you can see that .acct_input_bg element has width of 390px. 
In DevTool's box-model utility, the element is having 363px ( 390 - 20 - 7)!

I googled a bit and found that [Paul Irish blogged about the problem](http://bit.ly/1bfMrhO), but I have boostrap.css which applies proper box-sizing element. I also found less helpful here on stackoverflow in [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835600/input-field-width-and-padding-in-chrome) [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388862/inline-block-div-not-applying-padding-correctly).

Thanks for helping out!

[image: input width and padding mismatch]

Comment: It says right there in the top left of your screenshot, that the element has `-webkit-box-sizing: border-box` applied … so you what exactly are wondering about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by Bootstrap.
[The default box sizing is `content-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing#Values), and Bootstrap is changing it to `border-box`, and that is the behavior you're seeing.

Have a look at [the source code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/a92aea5127e805cb44c9d606a71c48fa19ee157b/less/scaffolding.less#L11):

```
// Reset the box-sizing
//
// Heads up! This reset may cause conflicts with some third-party widgets.
// For recommendations on resolving such conflicts, see
// http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#third-box-sizing
* {
.box-sizing(border-box);
}
*:before,
*:after {
.box-sizing(border-box);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important;
```

Comment: I used -webkit-box-sizing: initial; to reset that behavior to browser's default. Thanks